# Ionic 3 works with syntax error, but can't build with this error

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am building a weather application with ionic 3, my problem is when the response comes back (and I know the names of its keys) when I call one of them WeatherStorm (the IDE I am using) says:

> property 'current_observation' does not exist on type object"

but the application is working when I try it on 'localhost:8100/ionic-lab'.
 
Until now no problem, I took this and said that the problem is from the editor(cuz it is working and giving correct results) but when I was trying to build the app to generate apk the Windows-Command-Line and Git-Bash both complained about this error. The exact command causing me the trouble is: "ionic cordova build --release android".

Here is the call method:

```
getWeather(city, state) {
  return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + state + '/' + city + '.json')
    .map(res => res);
}
```

And here is the response (here comes the error at current_observation):

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(
        this.location.city,
        this.location.state
      ).subscribe(weather => {
        this.weather = weather.current_observation;
        console.log(this.weather);
      })

      }).catch(()=> {

      });
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way , it will do the trick**

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(
        this.location.city,
        this.location.state
      ).subscribe(weather => {
        this.weather = weather["current_observation"];
        console.log(this.weather);
      }).catch(()=> {

      });
```

Comment: I love your solution. You know I have been searching for the solution for about 3 hrs, you just saved my day, thannkkkkk youuuuu :D

Comment: This work around might have solved the problem but is not the appropriate solution. Not the angular way to do so. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379867/ionic-3-works-with-syntax-error-but-cant-build-with-this-error/49380040#49380040

Comment: @AmitChigadani, not a work around bro. Since it's a dynamic data and no data type is declared/casted , this is the way to go.

Comment: The recommendation is to declare the data type that is expected. Doing so it is easy to access all the other properties as well. If there is no data type and it is a free variable, poor design it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should also declare the type of `weather` variable so that you don't get an error.

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(
        this.location.city,
        this.location.state
      ).subscribe((weather : Weather) => {
        this.weather = weather.current_observation;
        console.log(this.weather);
      })

      }).catch(()=> {

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

After solve this bug, Sometime it's not work in IDE/Editor.
So restart your computer and `ionic serve` your project again and try this code.

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(this.location.city, this.location.state)
      .subscribe((weather) =>{
        this.weather = weather["current_observation"];
      });
```

Comment: I try to describe more to solve this bug easily. Like restart my machine. Because i solved this bug but for restarting my machine ,editor continue showed me the false result/previous result.That's why i think user need to know it. And sachine already solve it ,that's why, i gave him a upvote. Thanks @Utpaul

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of data in the `Observable` returned. The following function states that it will return an `Observable` having data of type `Weather`. 
So at the place where you are subscribing it will expect a value of type `Weather` and will check type accordingly.

```
getWeather(city, state): Observable<Weather> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + state + '/' + city + '.json')
      .map<Weather>(res => res);
}

// place Weather in its own file and import in places where you use it.
class Weather {
   current_observation: any;
   ...otherKeys
}
```

If you don't care about any of these, you can try marking the return type as `any`

```
getWeather(city, state): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + state + '/' + city + '.json')
      .map(res => res);
}
```

Also, make sure your project and your IDE are using the same version of Typescript.